# JHBuild runtime error "Failed to close %s stream" (MacOS)

Tags: jhbuild

I started a JHBuild with the wrong arguments (forgot 'build') and hit control-C at what appears to have been the wrong moment.

Now when I try any `JHBuild` command, e.g. `jhbuild bootstrap`, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gnucashdev/Source/jhbuild/jhbuild/config.py", line 197, in load
    execfile(filename, config)
  File "/Users/gnucashdev/.jhbuildrc", line 408, in <module>
    execfile(_userrc)
  File "/Users/gnucashdev/.jhbuildrc-custom", line 22, in <module>
    setup_sdk()
  File "/Users/gnucashdev/.jhbuildrc", line 260, in setup_sdk
    gcc = _popen("xcrun -f gcc")
  File "/Users/gnucashdev/.jhbuildrc", line 41, in _popen
    raise RuntimeError, "Failed to close %s stream" % cmd_arg
RuntimeError: Failed to close xcrun -f gcc stream
jhbuild: could not load config file
```

I've tried re-installing `jhbuild` with

```
 ./gtk-osx-build-setup.sh
```

but the next step - i.e.

```
jhbuild bootstrap
```

yields the above error.  Some file appears to have been compromised, perhaps truncated.  But I'm having a hard time figuring out which.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. `xcrun` is returning an error, probably due to an incorrect environment variable. In my case, I was running `jhbuild` while in a `jhbuild shell`, which caused the `SDKDIR` environment variable to contain 2 copies of the path to the SDK directory. Exiting the jhbuild shell fixed the problem.